# Why I can't send the file to server?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, post, server

There is a server, there is a web service (asp.net).

On the server, through postman I send img in base64 format, it appears in the specified folder, everything works fine.

And here already from the outside when I send too the status OK, upload goes, but in a folder on the server does not appear.

In what there can be a problem?

Comment: Hey, people here would like to help. But you are not helping us to help you with this kind of question. Please refer to this link regarding "How do I ask a good question" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thnx for your refer, i know what my english isn't good, but if someone understands the essence of the issue, help me, pls

Comment: The English is not the problem. It's the construction of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood what was my problem:

When i send file from the server itself, the file was saved by the specified path in the method, and from the outside the default path is different.

Perhaps someone will help in this information.